# Only white screen on startup

Tags: startup-file

my blender (version 2.93.1) was working fine yesterday and i tried to open today and it gave me a white screen. tried rolling back my drivers, putting opengl32.dll but nothing worked. any idea how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Specs:

AMD Ryzen 5 3600x - 6 core processor 3.80Ghz
16 GB ram
Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 super
Windows 10 -  64-bit
**Huion Graphics Tablet**  - NOTE - this turned out to be the cause of this particular problem, however the question was closed before the solution was discovered. To any users experiencing the problem of a white screen at startup, possibly also occurring with Adobe software as well, the problem may lie with the driver of a Graphics Tablet input device (in this case Huion), if conventional GPU driver fixes are not solving the problem. I will post this as an official answer, should the question become re-opened.

Comment: Any chance you're using a drawing pad?

Comment: ah yes, i use a drawing tablet. not the right forum but I cant open any adobe related softwares in my computer either. every single one is not responding. Maybe blender was one of them, just don't know.

Comment: I saw someone say the driver for their drawing pad was crashing blender (other software as well - possibly adobe). Either way, fixing the driver or removing it seemed to work for them.

Comment: damn bro, you just saved my life right there. i just quit the huion driver and everything was opening. Thank you very very very much. Lost one day of work but thank you very much, it worked and i am so happy. Maybe god bless you. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: Hey. glad it worked. I'm gonna try and re-open the question and write it as an official answer, if that's ok with you. When I was researching the source of the problem, there were a lot of posts where people had the problem, but there were no responses - I figure one more correct answer out there can't hurt.

Comment: sure sure go ahead. i researched whole day and couldn't find anything like literally anything related to drawing tablet driver crashes leading to this. quite new as well as unusual for me as well. Thank you for your help as well as your time.